# Configurar permisos por grupo en Django

Tags: python, django, permisos, configuración

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto de Django en el que me exigen que la administración de usuarios, grupos y permisos se haga solamente por el panel de administración.

Así que eché mano al django.contrib.auth. Creé un login con este view.py

```
# Django
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 

from django.contrib import messages

def LoginView(request):
    """
    Login
    Se utiliza el modulo de usuarios de Django
    """
    template_name = "login.html"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)


        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if request.user.groups.filter(name="Administradores").exists():
                return redirect('inicio')
            else:
                return redirect('listarS')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error en el ingreso')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Error en CUIT o contraseña')

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)

def LogoutView(request):
    """
    Logout de Django
    """
    template_name = "login.html"
    context = {}
    logout(request)
    return redirect(request, 'login.html', context)
```

Los grupos son dos "administradores" y "operadores", siendo que los usuarios del grupo operadores sólo tienen permisos en un modelo en particular y nada más. Así que configuré los permisos del grupo de esta manera:

[image: Permisos del grupo operadores]

Pero cuando agrego un usuario a este grupo:

[image: Grupo del usuario operador]

Al logearse, ocurre que este usuario puede hacer cualquier cosa (agregar, modificar, borrar o listar) en cualquier modelo de la aplicación.

En concreto: **¿Cómo debo hacer para que los usuarios del grupo operadores sólo tengan los permisos de ese grupo?**

Estoy usando Django 4.1.3